# Find subnet mask from IP address

Tags: c#

I have an IP address and I want to calculate its corresponding Subnet mask..Can some one give me some sample IP's and its subnet mask.. I have used this code.. Is this correct?

```
static public string ReturnSubnetmask(String ipaddress)
    {
        uint firstOctet = ReturnFirtsOctet(ipaddress);
        if (firstOctet >= 0 && firstOctet <= 127)
            return "255.0.0.0";
        else if (firstOctet >= 128 && firstOctet <= 191)
            return "255.255.0.0";
        else if (firstOctet >= 192 && firstOctet <= 223)
            return "255.255.255.0";
        else return "0.0.0.0";
    }

    static public uint ReturnFirtsOctet(string ipAddress)
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress iPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        byte[] byteIP = iPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
        return (uint)byteIP[0];
    }
```

Comment: check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knom/2008/12/31/ip-address-calculations-with-c-subnetmasks-networks/

Comment: When `10.0.0.0/24` can include IPs `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.254` and `10.0.0.0/16` can include IPs `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.255.254`, how could you work out the subnet mask of an IP such as `10.0.0.5`?

Comment: is the code correct/. @john

Comment: @AnuAravind My point is that I don't think that code can be created to find a subnet mask from an IP address alone since larger subnet ranges can entirely contain smaller ones, as in the example I provided above. If that IP address was the _broadcast_ address, then I imagine this might be possible, but otherwise I don't think it is.

Comment: Class IP addresses are deprecated and can still be subnetted for other purposes and you haven't been able to calculate subnets from addresses since CIDR was put in common use.